# Custom created android-calendar gets deleted after restarting the device

Tags: android, calendar

I have created a new calendar with the following code using Android 2.3.5:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14)
    {
        ContentValues calendar = new ContentValues();

        calendar.put("_sync_account", "Com2Cal");
        calendar.put("_sync_account_type", "LOCAL");
        calendar.put("name", "Com2Cal");
        calendar.put("displayName", "Com2Cal");
        calendar.put("color", 0xFF008080);
        calendar.put("access_level", 700);
        calendar.put("sync_events", 1);
        calendar.put("timezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        calendar.put("ownerAccount", "Com2Cal");
        calendar.put("hidden", 0);
        Uri conentUri;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8)
        {
            conentUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        }
        else
        {
            conentUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
        }

        Uri newRow = context.getContentResolver().insert(createCompleteUri(conentUri), calendar);

        Log.v(TAG, newRow.toString());
    }
```

and

```
private static Uri createCompleteUri(Uri uri)
{
    Uri.Builder b = uri.buildUpon();
    b.appendQueryParameter("caller_is_syncadapter", "true");
    b.appendQueryParameter("account_name", "Com2Cal");
    b.appendQueryParameter("account_type", "LOCAL");
    Uri calUri = b.build();
    Log.d("completeUri", calUri.toString());
    return calUri;
}
```

The calendar has successfully been created as I can see it in the calendar app. But after restart the device, the calendar no longer exists. What am I missing?

Comment: Where do you create this calendar (onCreate, onResume, somewhere else)?

Comment: No, not really.
Probably I had to create a SyncAdapter.